# Extracting salt from tx's to the CREATE2 deployer contract 0x4e59b44847b379578588920ca78fbf26c0b4956c

Tags: contract-verification, create2, salt, sourcify

I've noticed a pattern in deploying CREATE2 contracts and now I'm trying to find out the `salt` used. The reason is, for verifying contracts with [CREATE2 on Sourcify](https://docs.sourcify.dev/docs/create2/) `salt` and the `deployerAddress` are needed.

So there's this contract [`0x4e59b44847b379578588920ca78fbf26c0b4956c`](https://etherscan.io/address/0x4e59b44847b379578588920ca78fbf26c0b4956c) deployed on many chains which seems to serve the purpose of CREATE2 deploying a contract. It takes some padding + salt (I guess) + creation bytecode and deploys. I'd appreciate some explanation on this contract's code either, because I couldn't find anything despite its popularity.

I was able to verify the [ERC-4337 implementation](https://etherscan.io/address/0x0576a174D229E3cFA37253523E645A78A0C91B57) (`0x0576a17...`) because coincidentally the `salt` was `0`. Here are the first bytes of the [tx.input](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xe48e6d58fe941b0d152a43ac197d5869b065a0c0bea405c7fbeeeee8051d66c6) that created `0x0576a17...`:

```
0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000060a08060405234620000...
```

Now I'm trying to verify a [Uniswap Contract](https://etherscan.io/address/0x000000000022d473030f116ddee9f6b43ac78ba3#code) (`0x000000...`) also deployed by `0x4e59b4`. Here are the first of the [tx.input](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xf2f1fe96c16ee674bb7fcee166be52465a418927d124f5f1d231b36eae65d377) that created `0x000000...`:

```
0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000d3af2663da51c1021500000060c0346100bb574660a0...
```

Could someone explain how can I find the `salt` used and maybe in general what's going on?

Answer (score 2):

It was quite easy. The salt is the first 32 bytes of the tx.input. So for `0x000000...` it was:

```
0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000d3af2663da51c10215000000
```

Answer (score 1):

[0x4e59b44847b379578588920cA78FbF26c0B4956C](https://etherscan.io/address/0x4e59b44847b379578588920ca78fbf26c0b4956c) is foundry [Create2Deployer](https://book.getfoundry.sh/misc/precompile-registry?highlight=create2d#registry). It's more common to see it in forge script :)

And for tx.input: `32-byte salt + creationCode`